# How to spread data based on two ID's and fill new columns with response from corresponding column

Tags: r, spread, dcast

This is my dataset

```
ID <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3)
ID_2<-c("A","A","B","B","C","C")
Type<-c("EM","PA","EM","PA","EM","PA")
INT <- c("R", "I", "S", "S", "R", "R")
ORG <- c("EC", "EC", "KP", "KP", "MM", "MM")

Data_sum<- data.frame(ID, ID_2, Type, INT, ORG)
Data_sum
```

I would like to data to look like this.  So the rows are condensed based on "ID" and "ID_2" and spreading the column "Type" into individual columns and filling the responses with the information from "INT"

```
ID         ID_2      EM      PA       ORG  
1          A         R       I        EC
2          B         S       S        KP
3          C         R       R        MM
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(Data_sum), ID + ID_2 + ORG ~ Type, value.var = "INT")

#    ID ID_2 ORG EM PA
# 1:  1    A  EC  R  I
# 2:  2    B  KP  S  S
# 3:  3    C  MM  R  R
```

Comment: When I use this code on my actual data I get an error "Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length".  Additionally, instead of the "Type" columns filling with their corresponding R, I, S, etc.  They are filling with numbers (zero and one).  Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: then your ID-ID2-ORG combinations are not unique.. So you havve more than one EM and/or PA value for each row (there are the numbers you see)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution.

```
library(tidyr)

pivot_wider(
  Data_sum,
  id_cols = c(ID, ID_2, ORG),
  names_from = Type,
  values_from = INT
)
## A tibble: 3 x 5
#     ID ID_2  ORG   EM    PA   
#  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1     1 A     EC    R     I    
#2     2 B     KP    S     S    
#3     3 C     MM    R     R
```